# Changing the text of a hyperlink in asp.net on click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I am trying to change the text of my hyperlink after the user has clicked it. Here is the hyperlink:

```
   <asp:hyperlink id="OpenClose" runat="server" onclick="OpenClose_Click" AutoPostBack="true">Close</asp:hyperlink>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenClose.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OpenClose_Click");
}
protected void OpenClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OpenClose.Text == "Close")
        OpenClose.Text = "Open";
    else
        OpenClose.Text = "Close";
}
```

The problem is that it does not seem to see the function OpenClose_Click. I am not sure why. Is there another method to do this or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Here is the entire aspx code

```
   <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="../MasterPageLite.master"                  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testPageLoad2.aspx.cs" Inherits="BuilderPages_testPageLoad2" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>


 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div class="left_side">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

 This is the second test page I am making. Practice collapse and expand panels!

<div class="msg_list">
<h3 class="msg_head">Header-1</h3>
<div class="msg_body">
Collapse this panel!!
<asp:button runat="server" text="Can you see me?" />
 </div>
<h3 class="msg_head">Header-2</h3>
<div class="msg_body">
Congratulations you opened the panel!!
</div>
<h3 class="msg_head">Header-3</h3>
<div class="msg_body">
The third panel has been opened!!
</div>
</div>

</form>
</div>

<div class="right_side">
<div class="lBorder">
<asp:Panel ID="OpenClosePanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<asp:HyperLink id="OpenClose" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline;">Show/Hide</asp:HyperLink>

 </div>

 <div class="rscontent">
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum... 
 </p>
 <p>
 Nulla... 
 </p>
 <p>
 Vivamus... 
 </p>
 <p>
 Phasellus... 
 </p>
 <p>
 Aenean... 
 </p>
 </div>

 </div>
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: You're binding a Javascript function to the hyperlink in the Page_Load. What's it do when you step into it using debug?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784555/how-to-use-the-onclick-event-for-hyperlink-using-c-sharp-code

Comment: @Rake36 the problem with that is that I need to change the text of the control on click and using the method in that post seems like it isn't possible to do that. I have tried to implement it using that method but I can't figure out a way to check for the onclick and change the text accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a LinkButton instead of a HyperLink control, like this:

**Markup**:

```html
<asp:LinkButton id="OpenClose" 
                runat="server" 
                OnClick="OpenClose_Click" 
                AutoPostBack="true" 
                Text="Close"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Code-Behind**:

```cs
protected void OpenClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OpenClose.Text == "Close")
    {
        OpenClose.Text = "Open";
    }
    else
    {
        OpenClose.Text = "Close";
    }
}
```

The `LinkButton` class derives from the `Button` class thus it has similar events to a button, which is the effect you want, but it renders like a hyperlink.

Comment: I tried that and the problem is I have to wrap it in a form tag and I cannot do that since I already have a form tag elsewhere at least thats what it says when I add the form tag

Comment: To be more specific @Karl the new error is `A page can have only one server-side Form tag.`

Comment: Sure but Ill explain why its set up the way it is. I have the web form split into two sides the left and the right. this is why I have already you see a form in the dive called `left_side`. So I cannot use another. I think this problem will have to be solved using some jquery Ill post the code as an edit above

Comment: Okay, why cannot the left side and right side live within the form?

Comment: Let me try that and see if the layout holds up! @Karl

Comment: After changing the forms end location it worked with the linkbutton. thank you!

Comment: Great! Good luck with the rest of your development. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:hyperlink ...` is not a valid type of control since .NET is case sensitive.  Try changing it to:

`<asp:HyperLink ...`

I would also get rid of the code in your page load event.

Comment: Tried this but the error **Error: 'OpenClose_Click' is undefined** is still there.